# How are scars assigned?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1, pandemic-legacy

The rules say that characters should receive scars that have an outbreak.

But how do we determine which scar the character receives? Do we choose it ourselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get to choose! On page 5 of the [rules](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/26/94/2694b3fb-c718-4f87-9bdd-bbea0fdadcbe/zm7172_pandemic_legacys1_red_rules.pdf), under "scars":

> Characters can be mentally or physically damaged over the course of play. When this happens, choose an available scar and add it to your character’s
>   card.